# How to compute these equivalence classes in GAP?

Tags: math, gap-system

I have a group defined by `G := Group((1,2,3),(1,2,4),(5,6,7),(5,6,8),(1,2)(5,6));`. How can I compute the equivalence classes of elements in G (or a representative of each equivalence class) with respect to the equivalence relation a ~ b <=> there exist integers m,n such that a = c^n b c^m, where c is some fixed element of G?

Comment: Is this really a programming question?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes. How is this not a programming question?

Comment: Downvoted? Please explain.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand It is indeed a programming question about GAP (www.gap-system.org), but I suggest to migrate it to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gap where it will get more attention from GAP users.